# Preprocessing function for specific view by name

Tags: views, theming

I'm using drupal 7.29 . I'm trying to write the preprocess function for a specific view named front-page. I have written the following functions in my template.php file:

```
function bartik_sub_preprocess_views_view__front_page(&$variables) {

  kpr($variables);
}
```

The function for preprocessing view works normally (without the __front_page at the end), but the above function isn't being called. I did create the corresponding .tpl.php (views-view--front-page.tpl.php) file which is used  but the function still isn't being called. I watched a couple of tutorials where the preprocessing function for a specific view was written like this and it worked,  any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement `hook_theme` function to make views aware of your custom preprocess theme function. You can find a tutorial on this here: http://www.appnovation.com/blog/theming-view-within-your-module

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying for a couple of days and this solution is not working. The function

```
function bartik_sub_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  kpr($theme);
}
```

isn't being called. In a tutorial I watched (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Cfc11_sb5M) the guy just defines the preprocessing function and that is it. Even the Devel modul is suggesting

```
theme_hook_suggestion (String, 22 characters ) views_view__front_page
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Any idea?